# SCAN weaknesses relative to C-SCAN and N-Step-Scan

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, disk

My question concerns weaknesses of SCAN, and related algorithms for **disk scheduling** (the magnetic arm of a hard drive is slow to move. When we have multiple read/write jobs queued to different locations on the disk, we have to decide which jobs we service first.)

**Scan** moves in one direction only, satisfying all requests en route, until it reaches the last track in that direction or until there are no more requests in that direction. The service direction is then reversed and the scan proceeds in the opposite direction, again picking up all requests in order.

**C-Scan** restricts scanning to one direction only. Thus, when the last track has been visited in one direction, the arm is returned to the opposite end of the disk and the scan begins again.

**N-step-SCAN** segments the disk request queue into subqueues of
length N. Subqueues are processed one at a time, using SCAN. While a queue is being processed, new requests must be added to some other queue.

William Stallings makes the following claims in his book "Operating Systems":

> "It is not difficult to see that the SCAN policy favours jobs whose requests are for tracks nearest to both innermost and outermost tracks and favors the latest-arriving jobs. The first problem can be avoided via the C-SCAN policy, while the second problem is addressed by the N-step-SCAN policy."

**1. How does SCAN favour requests to outermost tracks?** I can imagine it spending more time around the centre and less time around the edges. How is one supposed to grasp the idea that it favors *both* the center *and* the edges - while neglecting areas between them?

**2. How does SCAN favour the latest-arriving jobs?** I understand that we would prefer to favour older jobs, but as far as I can tell, SCAN does not make a distinction between older/newer jobs and there is no implicit benefit for newer jobs over older jobs. To me it looks like an old job is just as likely to be serviced as a new job.

Comment: The only thing I can possibly help you with here is that I believe that by "both innermost and outermost track" the author means "both edges", not "the centre and both edges".

Answer (score 0):

**1. How does SCAN favour requests to outermost tracks?** Stallings means that the tracks on the edges are favoured. However, according to http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gkesden/412-18/fall01/ln/lecture16.html and I agree, this is inaccurate. For a detailed answer on this, check out that page.

**2. How does SCAN favour the latest-arriving jobs?** I'm confused by this too, I agree with you. It just depends on where the track arrived not when it arrived.